# Do foreign students always have to carry their passports with them?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, canada, legal, study

If I go out of my country to study, should I always carry my passport with me?

EDIT: I am a citizen of India. I have not currently applied but want to go to Canada. Sorry for not being clear about this.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Every country has its own rules about what documents visitors are expected to carry with them; what country is your homeland and what country are you studying in? Did your university or other institution provide any guidance on this matter?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question with the more details.

Comment: You are not required to carry a passport with you everywhere you go but if you have no other identification, it is helpful to have it when you need an ID. An example of a place that requires ID - casino. Having a soft and hard copy of the passport would be good too in case something happens. Scan it and put it on your phone, photocopy it and keep it in a different place than the original. You can carry the soft copy anywhere on your phone